# Two boxplots on the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have two different datasets with different numbers of observations. I would like to plot two boxplots on the same graph so it's easier to make comparison. I could plot one boxplot, but that would be hard to spot any discrepancy without them side by side.

I have some fake data.

```
Group A
V1    V2   V3    V4     V5
6.5   2    11    0.5    6
7     1    8     0.34   8
5.4   4    7.8   0.45   5
3.4   6    9.1   0.72   5

Group B
V1    V2   V3    V4     V5
5.0   5    9     0.4    7
2     7    5.2   0.69   5
3.2   2    2.9   0.79   2
6.8   9    6.5   0.43   6
4.7   3    3.8   0.49   4
5.5   4    7.4   0.94   3
```

I don't know how to graph this, so I don't have an example. I'll try my best to describe the plot. I would like to plot Variable 1 for Group A and B on the same graph. So on one graph, I would have a boxplot for Group A and another boxplot for Group B filled with data from V1. So the two boxplots would be side by side. With 5 variables, I would have 5 graphs, each with 2 boxplots side by side. Please let me know if I'm not being clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot` works best with "long format" data (e.g., with a column for each of value, variable, and group). You can rearrange your data as follows:

```
A <- read.table(text='V1    V2   V3    V4     V5
6.5   2    11    0.5    6
7     1    8     0.34   8
5.4   4    7.8   0.45   5
3.4   6    9.1   0.72   5', header=TRUE)

B <- read.table(text='V1    V2   V3    V4     V5
5.0   5    9     0.4    7
2     7    5.2   0.69   5
3.2   2    2.9   0.79   2
6.8   9    6.5   0.43   6
4.7   3    3.8   0.49   4
5.5   4    7.4   0.94   3', header=TRUE)

d <- rbind(cbind(stack(A), group='A'), cbind(stack(B), group='B'))
```

The first few rows look like this:

```
head(d)

##   values ind group
## 1    6.5  V1     A
## 2    7.0  V1     A
## 3    5.4  V1     A
## 4    3.4  V1     A
## 5    2.0  V2     A
## 6    1.0  V2     A
```

Now we can plot like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(group, values)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ind, scales='free_y')
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! May I ask what `facet_wrap(~ind, scales='free_y')` means?

Comment: `facet_wrap` separates the plots into multiple panels, and in this case we specify that we want them separated according to `ind` (the default name given to the variable column when we used `stack`. Otherwise the variables would all be pooled. And `scales='free_y'` allows the y-axes limits to be optimised for each panel (see `?facet_wrap`).

Answer (score 4):

The solution I came up with is to combine two `data.frame` and also a variable indicating which groups the observation belongs to. Then, you can use `melt` function in `reshape2` to transform the data into a `data.frame` ready for plotting. You can use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` to create separate plots for different variables.  This is a way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Combine two data.frame
df <- rbind(GroupA, GroupB)

# Create variable Group
df$Group <- rep(c("A", "B"), c(dim(GroupA)[1], dim(GroupB)[1]))

# Transform to long format
df <- melt(df, "Group")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Group, y=value)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~ variable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the names of your data sets are grpa (Group A) and grpb (Group B). First add a variable `Group` to each of them:

`grpa$Group <-"A"`

`grpb$Group <-"B"`

Then combine them into a single dataframe

`combined <- rbind(grpa,grpb)`

Then plot using ggplot like:

`ggplot(combined,aes(x= factor(Group), y=V1))+geom_boxplot()`

[image]

Label as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Adding a variable to the dataframes Group_A & Group_B as done from pervious users
Group_A$fac <- "A"
Group_B$fac <- "B"
Group_c <- rbind(Group_A,Group_B)
df <- melt(Group_c)

#You can plot the same in bwplot from library(lattice) 

bwplot(value~fac|variable,data=df,scales=list(relation="free"),as.table=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
group_a<-data.frame(
  V1 = c(6.5, 7, 5.4, 3.4),
  V2 = c(2, 1, 4, 6),
  V3 = c(11, 8, 7.8, 9.1),
  V4 = c(0.5, 0.34, 0.45, 0.72),
  V5 = c(6, 8, 5, 5)
  )
group_a
group_b<-data.frame(
  V1 =c(5.0,2,3.2,6.8,4.7,5.5),
  V2 =c(5,7,2,9,3,4),
  V3=c(9,5.2,2.9,6.5,3.8,7.4),
  V4=c(0.4,0.69,0.79,0.43,0.49,0.94),
  V5=c(7,5,2,6,4,3)
  )
group_b
# Create a new empty data frame with header
empty_df <- data.frame(Value = numeric(), var = character(), group = 
character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Loop through each column in group_a
for (col in names(group_a)) {
  # Extracting column values
  column_values <- group_a[[col]]
  # Create a temporary data frame to hold the extracted column
  temp_df <- data.frame(Value = column_values, var = col, group = "A")
  # Append the temporary data frame to empty_df
  empty_df <- rbind(empty_df, temp_df)
  }

for (colb in names(group_b)) {
 column_values<-group_b[,colb]
 tempp_df<- data.frame(Value=column_values, var = colb, group = "B")
 empty_df<-rbind(empty_df,tempp_df)
}
ggplot(empty_df, aes(x = group, y = Value)) +
geom_boxplot() +
facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free_y")
```

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1sve.png)